# React much slower on Firefox than Chrome?

Tags: performance, firefox, flexbox

My React page seems to be considerably slower in Firefox than in any other browser. For example if I click on a button to open a filter in Chrome it will take less than a second for the filter to be displayed on the page. If I do the same action in Firefox it takes 2-3 seconds for the filter to be displayed on the page.

Has anyone else ran into this problem? If so what did you do to fix it?

I tried using the React.addons.Perf functions to see if this could point me to the issue. There does seem to be a large gap between the wasted time between FF and Chrome but it still seems like it shouldn't take seconds to display on FF.

[Chrome Perf Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Q0er.png)

[FF Perf Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsARf.png)

Here are the versions of everything I am using:

- Firefox ESR v45.7.0
- Chrome v56.0.2924.87
- React 15.4.0

**Update**

I ran the profiler in FF to see what was taking so long and it looks like FF is taking most of the time to calculate the layout. Not sure what this means so I'm going to do more research on this.

Comment: Have you tried disabling all FF addons to make sure it isn't an interaction with one of them?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It didn't seem to speed anything up.

Comment: Are you using the production (minified) version of React, or the development build? The development build is slower. If you are using dev mode, you may see less of a difference between browsers with an optimized production build, and better speed in both cases.

Comment: Yeah I'm using the minified versions of react and react-dom

Comment: FF and Chrome are similar looking different animals like crocodile and alligator. One can tune a native JS code to work best with FF or Chrome. I mean React must have done with their preferences biased to Chrome. For instance [a dynamical programming test of mine](https://repl.it/FqimöplementSq/2) not only works faster in FF but also crashes on Chrome when the input is like more than 20K while with FF i could try up to 32768. So  guess it's best up to you to implement your code according to your own browser preference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the issue was not with react or javascript. I finally figured out that we just had too many deeply nested flex elements. This is what was taking firefox a long time to calculated the layout.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? Can you help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Pretty much to fix this I had to remove flex box styles from some nested elements like 3 or 4 levels deep. I don't exactly remember the number but to be honest it was just bad CSS by me. I just needed to spend the time to rethink if I needed to use flex box for some of the elements or not.